# TypeError: “NoneType” object is not callable in Google Colab (save model)

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to save the model that I have created.

Code where I'm getting the error.

```
earlystopper = EarlyStopping(patience=5, verbose=1)
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('model-dsbowl2018-1.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=16, epochs=5, callbacks=[earlystopper, checkpointer])
```

result error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-28bc6295bed2> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 earlystopper = EarlyStopping(patience=5, verbose=1)
      2 checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('model-dsbowl2018-1.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
----> 3 results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
      4                     validation_split=0.1,
      5                     batch_size=16, epochs=5,

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    855       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    856       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 857       return self._no_variable_creation_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    858     elif self._variable_creation_fn is not None:
    859       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Note: I am suffering from this error , I can't solved it and advanced thanks who are try to solve it and comment here for sharing the answer